# jQuery/AJAX - Whole page keeps reloading

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, reload

I'm having trouble loading a particular part of a page. It's nothing too fancy. The idea is when a user clicks next/prev day/week/month then the dates would load accordingly which is being handled in the backend. But before so I need to do some formatting on the front end which is the following:

```
<script>

//the prev/next link values will change when any one are clicked. This function will append the appropriate date to the link ranging from the prev month to the next month
function dateChange(dateInput){
//creating new instance of the date based on the date passed into the function  
var nextDay = new Date(dateInput); 
var nextWeek = new Date(dateInput); 
var nextMonth = new Date(dateInput); 
var prevDay = new Date(dateInput); 
var prevWeek = new Date(dateInput); 
var prevMonth = new Date(dateInput); 

//the date will change according to the date passed in from 1 day to 1 month
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate()+1);
nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate()+7);
nextMonth.setDate(nextMonth.getDate()+30); //need to add more complex code to handle next month
prevDay.setDate(prevDay.getDate()-1);
prevWeek.setDate(prevWeek.getDate()-7);
prevMonth.setDate(prevMonth.getDate()-30); //need to add more complex code to handle next month

//The following will go into another function which formats the date in such a way that vbscript can handle it.
nextDay = dateFormat(nextDay);
nextWeek = dateFormat(nextWeek);
nextMonth = dateFormat(nextMonth);
prevDay = dateFormat(prevDay);
prevWeek = dateFormat(prevWeek);
prevMonth = dateFormat(prevMonth);
//updating the values for the a tag in the onclick attribute. and appending to the strVar variable
var strVar="";
strVar += "             <div class=\"prev\">";
strVar += "                    <p>Prev<\/p>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+prevMonth+"')\">< month<\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+prevWeek+"')\">< week<\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+prevDay+"')\">< day<\/a>";
strVar += "                <\/div>";
strVar += "                ";
strVar += "                <div class=\"next\">";
strVar += "                 <p>Next<\/p>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+nextMonth+"')\">month ><\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+nextWeek+"')\">week ><\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+nextDay+"')\">day ><\/a>";
strVar += "                <\/div>";


//For each .title it finds, it will look for its child .dateselect and remove .dateselect child. It will then append new data to .dateselect with the updated values
$(".title").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find('.dateSelect').children().remove();
    $(this).find('.dateSelect').append(strVar);

    var boatName = $(this).next().attr('id');
      if(!$(this).next().hasClass('hide')){
          if(boatName == "SailingCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=SailingCatamaran&date="+dateInput+"");
              //alert(dateInput);
          }
          else if(boatName == "PowerCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date="+dateInput+"");
          }
          else{
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=nothing&date="+dateInput+"");
          }
      }
});
//Stops propagation so when day,week or month are clicked, the table won't disappear 
event.stopPropagation()

}

//Function is to receive the date in its raw format and convert it into YYYY,MM,DD
function dateFormat(theDate){

    theDate = ('0' + (theDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + ','
             + ('0' + theDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + ','
             + theDate.getFullYear();        
    return theDate;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    //alert(dateCounter);
    var dateCounter;
    if (dateCounter == null){
        var current = new Date();
        current = dateFormat(current);
        dateChange(current);
        dateCounter = 0; //anything but null
    }
    //alert(dateCounter);

    /*$("table").first().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date="+current+"", function(response, status, xhr){
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("table").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });*/

    $(".title").click(function(){
      $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
      var boatName = $(this).next().attr('id');
      if(!$(this).next().hasClass('hide')){
          if(boatName == "SailingCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=SailingCatamaran&date=");
          }
          else if(boatName == "PowerCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date=");
          }
          else{
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=nothing&date=");
          }
      }
      $(this).children().last().toggleClass("hide");
      $(this).find('.dateSelect').toggleClass("hide");

      //alert("title being clicked");
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I'm confused as to why the whole page keeps getting reloaded when I click on an a link which is the following:

```
    <div class="title">
        <h2>Catamarans</h2>
        <div class="dateSelect">
            <div class="prev">
                <p>Prev</p>
                <a href="" onClick="dateChange('someDate')">< month</a>
                <a href="" onClick="dateChange('someDate')">< week</a>
                <a href="" onClick="dateChange('someDate')">< day</a>
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                <p>Next</p>
                <a href="" onClick="dateChange('someDate')">month ></a>
                <a href="" onClick="dateChange('someDate')">week ></a>
                <a href="" onClick="dateChange('someDate')">day ></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expand hide">
            Click to Expand
        </div>
     </div>
```

I confirmed that the whole page keeps reloading because the document.ready keeps firing. The idea is to load the current date once. But the page keeps reloading and thus, the current date keeps getting used ALL the time. I just don't understand what is going on now. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're really making it hard for yourself with all those different date objects, placing jQuery code both inside and outside the DOM ready handler (which wont work if this script is in the head), and using empty href's, which is probably the issue, try at least doing `<a href="#" ....` to avoid issues with redirects, and preferably add a preventDefault in the event handler.

Comment: Mate I'm disgusted with my code as well, but the code I'm working with (previous client), makes this look like sunshine and rainbows. Mind you, I added the "#" in and it works.. Can you explain that in more depth as to why I needed a "#" if you feel like it? Or a link, whatever floats your boat haha!

Comment: An empty href will redirect to the same page, while hashes won't, they will scroll to that part of the page instead, as in `<a href="#myID">` will scroll to an element with the ID `myID`. The empty hash (#) scrolls to the top of the page, so it prevents the page from redirecting, but will scroll to the top if you have scrollbars, and to avoid the scrolling you need preventDefault in your event handlers, if you don't have scrollbars or don't mind the scrolling, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Ahh yes yes, I understand that. Makes so much more sense. Thank you so so much for that mate! You saved me a lot of time, and a lot of hair on my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[preventing default events in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$(".title").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
      var boatName = $(this).next().attr('id');
      if(!$(this).next().hasClass('hide')){
          if(boatName == "SailingCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=SailingCatamaran&date=");
          }
          else if(boatName == "PowerCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date=");
          }
          else{
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=nothing&date=");
          }
      }
      $(this).children().last().toggleClass("hide");
      $(this).find('.dateSelect').toggleClass("hide");

      //alert("title being clicked");
    });
```

Comment: Where abouts do I place this? I'm learning far too much doing this project haha! Love it! Excuse my n00bness.

Comment: Your going to want to use `e.preventDefault()` as the first line in the function after the `click` event is acted upon. The example on that page is almost identical to your situation with the `<a href=..>` links.

Comment: ahh ok, so having something like:
$(".title").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");

Would suffice? Is this what you meant? To stop URL pages from loading?

Comment: You bloody beauty! Thank you for you help. Like really, You saved me hours of googling. Wouldn't have thought of prevent.Default()
Again, thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. This also comes in handy when submitting forms, so keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
strVar += "<a href=\"\"...
```

Try using:

```
strVar += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\"...
```

But you wouldn't even NEED to do that if you assigned event handlers through jQuery. You could just called `e.preventDefault()`